# Improve Performance of categorical crossentropy on four dimensional prediction and target

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a Neural Network implemented in tensorflow that takes a batch of images and predicts a tensor with shape (batch_size, 9, 9, 10)

For each image in the batch the target (and the prediction) looks like this.
We predict an image with width 9, height 9 and depth 10. The depth of every pixel corresponds to a class so we have 10 classes.

So e.g. the prediction of pixel(0,0) with softmax looks like this [0, 0.8 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0.2 ,0 ,0,0]
and the target of the pixel(0,0) looks like this [0, 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

I want to use the classical cross entropy between these two tensors.

currently my loss is implemented like this:

```
def calculate_loss(prediction, target):
    '''
    prediction and target have shape (batch_size, 9, 9, 10)
    '''
    loss = 0
    for batch in range(0, BATCH_SIZE):
        for width in range(0,9):
            for heigth in range(0,9):
                loss += tf.losses.categorical_crossentropy(target[batch][width][height] , prediction[batch][width][height])
return loss
```

But with a high batch size (1024) this calculation takes 20 seconds.
And this is just way too slow.
Are there any already implemented functions in tensorflow/keras that can improve the performance of this loss? 
Or do you know if I can change the code to improve performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(target, prediction)
```

Is the answer.
I can then reduce sum the values of the output to get the same thing.
Don't forget to remove the sofmax layer in your model.